# $\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(2\pi R t)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fourier-analysis

As suggested by Reuns in [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312405/is-fx-lim-r-rightarrow-infty-int-rr-hatfwe2i-pi-xwdw). It is interesting that the problem  there boils down to the following limit:

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(2\pi R t)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Anyone has an idea.

Thanks so much.

Comment: The answer should be $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $2\pi Rt=x$, then $$I =\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-2\pi R}^{2\pi R} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx=2\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$$